# How would I go about setting up a Development enviroment?

Tags: php

Should I be looking at Subversion, a sub domain such as dev.site.com.

If you could provide links to articles or tutorials that would be great :)

Thank you.

(This is for developing websites in PHP)

Comment: probably better for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What os will you be developing on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use XAMPP on my Windows machine and SVN to checkout to my htdocs folder. I configure Apache's httpd-vhosts.conf like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        DocumentRoot "C:\XAMPP\htdocs\example.com\public"
        ServerName example.local

        ErrorLog "C:\XAMPP\htdocs\example.com\logs\error.log"
        CustomLog "C:\XAMPP\htdocs\example.com\logs\access.log" common

        SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
</VirtualHost>
```

In my index.php for example.com I have the following code to read APPLICATION_ENV:

```
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
        || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));
```

This will set it to 'production' if no value for APPLICATION_ENV is found.

Taken from: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html

In C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts I add an entry:

```
127.0.0.1 example.local
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually take one old computer, install a linux machine, 
subversion, trac, and use it's Apache to test my staff.

That should be a good enough setup for dev env for a small group of programmers, and you can make sure you code doesn't sit in a single place... (assuming you check in in time...)

The actual development will be done on my personal computer, using apache and a dev environment that speaks with subversion either fully integrated or using the shell. (explorer in my case)